# Overloading char with short

Tags: java

`char` size is 16 bits and short size is 16 bits. If we have a constructor that accepts `short` argument, if we pass char to it why it wont accept even when the size of char and short are same?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Coffee {

    Coffee(short s2) {
        System.out.println("short accepted");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coffee c=new Coffee('c');
    }
}
```

Why can't we pass a `char` to a constructor that accepts `short`?

Comment: `float` and `int` are both 32-bit data types yet you can't pass a `float` where an `int` is expected. The number of bits doesn't say a lot about a data type; the range of values that it can represent is the important thing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` is unsigned while `short` is signed... You cannot store all `char`-possible values in `short`.

`char` stores 16 bit: [0, 65535] while `short` stores 16 bit: [-32768, 32767].

For example, you cannot represent a `char` that has the decimal value 63000 in a `short` and a  `short` can store the value -213 while `char` cannot.

Note that if the compiler knows that the value **will** fit, it will allow that without the need of the explicit cast.

Refer to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to better understand this issue:

> `short`: The short data type is a 16-bit **signed** two's complement
>   integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of
>   **32,767** (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can
>   use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the
>   memory savings actually matters.
>
> `char`: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   **65,535** inclusive).

Answer (score 7):

[The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) defines the conversion from char to short as a *narrowing* conversion. And it's expected, since char is an unsigned 2-bytes integer, whereas short is a signed 2-bytes integer. So, half of the char values can't be represented by a short.

You thus have to explicitely cast the char to short to tell the compiler that you know such a conversion might lose information.